# Как обьеденить ячейки в docx Python

Tags: python, docx

Пытаюсь добиться такой таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не знаю как обьеденить ячейки колонки Factor в одну.
Моя таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
doc = docx.Document()
# данные таблицы без названий колонок
items = []
for i in range(len(report_doc.index)):
    items.append((report_doc.index[i][0], report_doc.index[i][1], report_doc.values[i][0]))

# добавляем таблицу с одной строкой
# для заполнения названий колонок
table = doc.add_table(1, len(items[0]))
table.style = 'Table Grid'
# Получаем строку с колонками из добавленной таблицы
head_cells = table.rows[0].cells
# добавляем названия колонок
for i, item in enumerate(['Factor', 'Year', 'World value']):
    p = head_cells[i].paragraphs[0]
    # название колонки
    p.add_run(item).bold = True
    # выравниваем посередине
    p.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
# добавляем данные к существующей таблице
for row in items:
    # добавляем строку с ячейками к объекту таблицы
    cells = table.add_row().cells
    for i, item in enumerate(row):
        # вставляем данные в ячейки
        cells[i].text = str(item)
doc.save('test1.docx')
```

items:

[('6', '2007', 0.55), ('6', '2008', 0.69), ('6', '2009', 0.66), ('6', '2010', 0.63), ('6', '2011', 0.67), ('6', '2012', 0.68), ('6', '2013', 0.64), ('6', '2014', 0.7), ('6', '2015', 0.66), ('6', '2016', 0.66), ('6', '2017', 0.66), ('6', '2018', 0.67), ('6', '2019', 0.65)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для объединения ячеек используйте метод `merge`, например:

`table.cell(1, 0).merge(table.cell(7, 0))`

Более подробная информация [здесь](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/table/cell-merge.html).

Вот один из возможных способов:

```py
import docx
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
from docx.enum.table import WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL

# данные таблицы без названий колонок
items = [('6', '2007', 0.55),
         ('6', '2008', 0.69),
         ('6', '2009', 0.66),
         ('6', '2010', 0.63),
         ('6', '2011', 0.67),
         ('6', '2012', 0.68),
         ('6', '2016', 0.66),
         ('6', '2017', 0.66),
         ('7', '2018', 0.67),
         ('7', '2019', 0.65)]

doc = docx.Document()
# добавляем таблицу с одной строкой
# для заполнения названий колонок

table = doc.add_table(1, len(items[0]))
table.style = 'Table Grid'
# Получаем строку с колонками из добавленной таблицы
head_cells = table.rows[0].cells
# добавляем названия колонок
for i, item in enumerate(['Factor', 'Year', 'World value']):
    p = head_cells[i].paragraphs[0]
    # название колонки
    p.add_run(item).bold = True
    # выравниваем посередине
    p.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER

merge_on = ''
merge_from = 0

# добавляем данные к существующей таблице
for k, row in enumerate(items):
    # добавляем строку с ячейками к объекту таблицы
    cells = table.add_row().cells
    for i, item in enumerate(row):
        if i == 0:
            if merge_on == item:
                # пропускаем одинаковые значения
                pass
            else:
                if k - merge_from > 1:
                    # есть дубли - объединяем
                    table.cell(merge_from + 1, 0).merge(table.cell(k, 0))
                    table.cell(merge_from + 1, 0).vertical_alignment = WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL.CENTER
                # открываем новый регион
                merge_on = item
                merge_from = k
                cells[i].text = str(item)
        else:
            # вставляем данные в ячейки
            cells[i].text = str(item)

if k - merge_from > 0:
    # в хвосте остались дубли - объединяем
    table.cell(merge_from + 1, 0).merge(table.cell(k + 1, 0))
    table.cell(merge_from + 1, 0).vertical_alignment = WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL.CENTER

doc.save('test1.docx')
```